# Parse.com Javascript SDK for app API or just plain iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to figure out the best way to develop API for my iPhone and Android app with Parse.

Parse has separate iOS and Android SDKs that can create and modify objects. It's good choice, but then I'll have to send push notifications and it's obligatory to use Javascript Cloud for this case (as far as I understand).

So I'm thinking about using just Javascript Cloud as a wrapper and doing all things with data on Parse side (without using iOS or Android SDKs).

Does it seem like a good choice or I should dive deeper into native SDKs to eliminate server-side even if it's hosted on Parse?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it's obligatory to use Javascript Cloud to send push notification. In iOS case:
https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

As you can see, you have 4 choices for sending push notifications: 
Parse website, REST API, inside the app itself and also from Cloud code.